# Google Maps: Draw polygon surrounding random locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a set of random locations. The location set will keep changing. I would like to draw a polygon surrounding these locations.

[image]

Can this be done in Google Maps and how? The map will be displayed on a website only, no mobile api required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called a convex hull. Here:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_convexhull.asp

I would cite the code but it belongs to @geocodezip who is the authority on google maps and runs an excellent site of examples. I suggest you check it out.